# Which life cycle method will be called when returning from another page in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, lifecycle

I have a page A, then navigate to page B, then go back. I want to know which life cycle method will be called on A, or event will be emitted?

Comment: are you using react-navigation?

Comment: yes, I'm using react-navigation, and subscribe to the willFocus, and didFocus event, but the callback didn't get called @MykWillis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/), you can subscribe to the `didFocus` and `didBlur` events to be notified when the user navigates to or from a screen.

You can set these up in your component's `componentDidMount` using the [addListener](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) method of `this.props.navigation` like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
        // user has navigated to this screen
    });

    this.props.navigation.addListener("didBlur", () => {
        // user has navigated away from this screen
    });
}
```

Comment: I called addListener in the component's constructor. can you explain why it won't work? Thank you

Comment: @Rocky I haven't seen your constructor, but `this.props` will not be defined in a component's constructor until/unless it calls the superclass, so perhaps that was the issue. It seems that, in general, the React team expects constructors to be pretty lightweight, with most work deferred until later in the lifecycle.  See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor and http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/